# Why using a non-returned method treats different?

Tags: php, methods

Here is a simplified of my code:

```
class myclass{

    public function one($called_from = null){
        if ( $called_from != 'two'){
            return $this->two();
        }
        echo 'done';
    }

    public function two(){
        return $this->one(__FUNCTION__);
    }
}

$obj = new myclass;
$obj->one();
```

Now I want to add another method to do that comparison *(I'm talking about that `if` statement into `myclass::one`)*. So here is the new code:

```
class myclass{

    public function one($called_from = null){
        $this->three($called_from);
        echo 'done';
    }

    public function two(){
        return $this->one(__FUNCTION__);
    }

    public function three($called_from){
        if ( $called_from != 'two'){
            return $this->two();
        }
    }  
}

$obj = new myclass;
$obj->one();
```

But it treats different than the first version of the code. Why? I cannot explain what's the different, because it needs to show my other codes which are exists in reality.

Anyway, do you have any idea how can I do that comparison *(into `myclass::one`)* by another method with keeping the exact behavior in the whole process?

---

Also for my information *(not related to the question)*, do you know why that line will be executed **twice** in [this](https://3v4l.org/aVZD7) code? I expect it should be executed once.

Comment: In the second example you call `one` which echos _done_ and calls `three` which calls `two` which calls `one` which echos _done_ again. Also, `three` is never called from `two`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver When I call `one`, I expect it be stopped when it sees `return $this->two();`. So just one time it sees `echo 'done';`.

Comment: No, `return` just allows you to return a value to the caller and that value will be whatever `$this->two()` returns (if anything).

Comment: It is a bad idea to track where the method is called from. If you need indirect recursion (`one()` calls `two()` that calls `one()` again) then identify the stop condition and express it either as an argument of the two methods or as a property of the object. Don't take decisions based on the method names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the sequence of operations in the second code:

1. Call `one()` with no argument, so `$called_from = null`.
2. Call `three(null)`.
3. In `three`, the `if` succeeds, so it calls `two()`.
4. Call `one("two")`.

   1. Call `three("two")`
   2. The `if` fails, so `three` just returns.
   3. Echo `"done"`.
5. Echo `"done"`

Since `one` is called twice, it echoes `done` twice.

Comment: As a consult, I've some complex queries into `myclass::one()` *(instead of `echo 'done;'`)*, So executing them twice is waste processing. What algorithm do you suggest to execute `myclass::one()` once in any way? *(I'm talking about executing codes that are after comparison)*

Comment: Put it into the `else`, like I said.

Comment: So you mean I have to go with the first version of my code?

Comment: It's hard to give a good answer without understanding what you're really trying to do. Using `__FUNCTION__` like this seems like very fragile coding.

Comment: Sadly yes. I don't use any framework and I myself have to design the whole algorithm. Also I'm somewhat unskillful. That's why my code looks fragile.

Comment: Anyway, I will appreciate if you trace the code with adding `echo` into `else`. 
 How will it be executed?

Comment: Sorry, I got mixed up between the two versions, there's no `if` in `one` in the 2nd version.

Comment: Ok, just please tell me why this executes once? https://3v4l.org/sl4RJ Is't that exactly the same as my code in the question?

Comment: When `$called_from` matches, it returns from `index`, so it never adds 1 to `$i`.